# NULL values in mysql query -- versions matter?

Tags: mysql, null

I am doing a query against a mysql database.

There's a column called `source` with a default value of `NULL` used to tag remote data.

On my dev server I used a query like `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source` -- this works fine and removed all the rows with a value in `source`.

On the live server, this query fails to delete any rows. I assume I need to use `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source IS NOT NULL`.

However, it seems odd that there would be a difference in how mysql treats `NULL` values. Does this behaviour vary by mysql version? Or do I need to be looking for a different reason for the failure of this query on the live server?

Comment: Usually one says: `DELETE FROM x WHERE y=z` and not `WHERE y`.

Comment: Why don't you do a `SELECT` on both and compare the results.

Comment: @tadman Nothing unusual about `WHERE y`

Comment: It should work, but `IS NOT NULL` makes the intent perfectly clear.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: it's illegal SQL (unless `y` is a **true** boolean column - which MySQL doesn't have), but MySQL has never really cared about correct SQL grammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source
```

and

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source is not null
```

are two completely different things due to MySQL's broken expression handling.

If `source` is a numeric column (integer, decimal, ..) the the first one will delete all rows with a `source` greater than zero.

For an example see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87325/1

If `source` is a character value, MySQL will try to convert the contents to a number, if that works the row will be deleted if that number is greater than zero.

See here for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ebad/1

The reason why the (essentially broken) first query works on one database and not on the other might have to do with the values in the column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name-- thanks! That's very helpful information. The odd part is that the data in the column should be identical in both databases, since they're essentially duplicates-- just the server is different and the mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write statements with potentially ambiguous conditions?
I suggest you always write complete conditions in your MySQL queries:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source IS NULL;
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE source=0; /* and so on */
```

It makes the code easier to understand, and you are less likely to make mistakes.
I recommand doing the same thing when writing code in other languages.

Comment: @Jocelyn-- the reason was that there's no set value for `source`-- it could be basically anything. So in that case `IS NOT NULL` would be the more correct way to write the query, I'm just not sure why it works on one DB but not another.